# Set image coordinates programmatically

Tags: c#, image, microsoft-metro

Rather than declaring an image and setting the source from the xaml file, can someone do the initialization part, set the image coordinates, and set the source completely in the code?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Create Image Element
Image myImage = new Image();
myImage.Width = 200;

// Create source
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

// BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block
myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\Water Lilies.jpg");

// To save significant application memory, set the DecodePixelWidth or   
// DecodePixelHeight of the BitmapImage value of the image source to the desired  
// height or width of the rendered image. If you don't do this, the application will  
// cache the image as though it were rendered as its normal size rather then just  
// the size that is displayed. 
// Note: In order to preserve aspect ratio, set DecodePixelWidth 
// or DecodePixelHeight but not both.
myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
myBitmapImage.EndInit();
//set image source
myImage.Source = myBitmapImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Image specifying the source:

```
Image myImage = new Image();
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/YourSource", UriKind.Relative)); //Or UriKind.Absolute depending in the path
myImage.Source = bitmapImage;
```

If you want to place the image into some coordenates you can place a Canvas behind and place the image using Canvas coordenates. Use:

```
 _myCanvas.Children.Add(myImage);  //To add your image to Canvas, declared on Xaml or previously created and added to your control
Canvas.SetTop(myImage, 100);   //Set Y coordenate relative to Canvas initial point
Canvas.SetLeft(myImage, 100);  // Set X
```